# how to search particular string from $stdout and store whole $stdout in text file if string is found using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, http, stdout

I want to search particular string that will be there in $stdout that I print on console using  http.set_debug_output($stdout) . I want to search string "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *\r\n"  from $stdout and if string found want to store $stdout in text file.

Comment: Wait. In the string you are testing for, is the `*` a wildcard, or is it the litteral `*`? Also, must it be `\r\n`, or can it just be the local OS's line break character. That will increase portability.

Answer (score 1):

`$stdout` has some special restrictions in ruby. By default it is opened for reading only (obviously), so to seek/read lines that you've written, you have to replace it as a `File`. This will suffice:

```
$stdout = File.new("stdout", "w+")
puts "some string"
```

`Kernel#puts` will use `$stdout` by default, so this sets you up perfectly. What you have to implement is checking, it can be a little tricky, but here's one way to approach it.

```rb
$stdout = File.new("stdout", "w+")
puts "some string"
old = $stdout
$stdout = IO.try_convert(STDOUT)
old.rewind
old.lines.each do |line|
  puts 'contains requested data' if line == "some string\n"
end
```

Few things to note on the comparison, puts places `\n` automatically at the end of your string. To escape that `\n` so it matches the previous input, you **have to** put it in the `""` quotes.

Comment: getting error for above code: `ERROR: undefined method 'try_convert' for IO:Class`

Comment: @farnoy Your comment / question helped me identify an issue with my script running from cron. The cron was using an older ruby version (installed as root). Whereas, I installed latest ruby via RVM, for a particular user. Thank you!